# Como deixar app em execução em 2° plano?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Tenho uma activity e quero que ela fique em execução em 2° plano, tempo permanente, sei que vai gastar bateria do cellular mas preciso de ajuda .
 O código que tenho para implementar é uma webView este :

```
     new CountDownTimer(RESTART_TIME, 1000) {
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {}

       public void onFinish() {
       recreate();
    }
     }.start();
```

Alguém pode ajudar ?

Comment: Este ta com informação diferente .

Comment: Amtes eu procurava execução de tempo em tempo agora quero so 2°plano.